# Multi variable assignment in Scala

Tags: scala

I am reading a book in scala and one of the exercises is as follows:

*Come up with one situation where the assignment `x = y = 1` is valid in Scala. (Hint: Pick a suitable type for x.)*

The 2 solutions I could come up with are:

```
val x, y : Int = 1
val x, y = (1, 2)
```

Have I missed another way that the exercise is looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"valid" and "useful" don't necessarily mean the same thing :)

```
 scala> var y = 2
 y: Int = 2

 scala> val x = y = 1
 x: Unit = ()

 scala>
```

Comment: `def x_=(body: => Unit)` could be useful.